# MATLAB 2013a GUI saving handles fails in checkbox callback

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, handles

I'm making a GUI that reads out data from a measurement board via a serial interface. It consists of 8 channels and I want to be able to enable and disable the channels in the figure plot, but the state of my variable handles.channelsEnable isn't saved.

When opening the GUI: handles.channelEnable = [0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0];
While running the GUI I want to modify a handles.channelEnable. Inside the callback function of a checkbox it is changed, but not outside the function. I'm using guidata(hObject,handles) to save the changes made. Why aren't the changes made to handles.channelEnable saved?

```
    % --- Executes on button press in checkbox2.
    function checkbox2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to checkbox2 (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    % Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of checkbox2
        handles.channelEnable(2) = get(hObject,'Value');
        guidata(hObject, handles);
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `guidata` to include a new handle in the `handles` variable, but whenever you want to use `handles` you must call `guidata` to obtain them. The variable `handles` as input variable of the callback won't have it included.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand you.

Do you mean that I have to add guidata(hObject) to get the handles? So the code looks like this:


     % --- Executes on button press in checkbox2.
     function checkbox2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

      handles
      guidata(hObject);
      handles
      handles.channelEnable(2) = get(hObject,'Value');
      guidata(hObject,handles);
      end

It does not make any difference with or without. In both cases all handles are known (also channelEnable)l

Comment: I mean that when you callback is called, you will receive `handles` as input variable, but it will not contain the full list of handles.
If you want to have all of them (which you also included before with `guihandles(hObject, handles)`), you have to call `guihandles` again inside the callback to get ALL.
Is it clear now? :)

Comment: I still don't get it. It makes no difference, I think I'm still doing something wrong. Could you write down the code I have to put in the checkbox callback (literally)? When I look in the MATLAB documentation it says "If you use GUIDE, you do not need to call guihandles to create a structure, because GUIDE generates a handles structure that contains the GUI's handles. You can add your own data to it". See [link](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html?searchHighlight=guidata)

Comment: But you have included a new control in `handles` manually.
To have the whole list of handles just put 'handles = guihandles;' after 'function checkbox2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)' (that is to say, the first line after the checkbox callback is called).
If you still have problems, see @excaza 's answer also.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! Now I understand. At beginning of EVERY function or callback (not only the callback of the checkbox) you have to load the handles structure with 'handles = guidata(hObject);' and at the end of EVERY function or callback you have to save the handles structure with 'guidata(hObject,handles);'. My fault was that I didn't load the handles structure again in the function where I used channelEnable.

Answer (score 1):

@YisasL's answer is the correct one, but I wanted to clarify it a bit.

When providing an input variable to a callback function, the variable that is passed when you invoke the callback is that variable *as it exists when the callback is defined*. You can see this with a simple example:

```
function testcode
handles.mainwindow = figure();

handles.button1 = uicontrol( ...
    'Style','pushbutton', ...
    'Units','normalized', ...
    'Position',[0.05 0.05 .30 .90], ...
    'String','Button1', ...
    'Callback',{@button1,handles} ...
    );
handles.button2 = uicontrol( ...
    'Style','pushbutton', ...
    'Units','normalized', ...
    'Position',[0.35 0.05 .30 .90], ...
    'String','Button2', ...
    'Callback',{@button2,handles} ...
    );
handles.button3 = uicontrol( ...
    'Style','pushbutton', ...
    'Units','normalized', ...
    'Position',[0.65 0.05 .30 .90], ...
    'String','Button3', ...
    'Callback',{@button3,handles} ...
    );
end

function button1(~,~,handles)
fieldnames(handles)
end

function button2(~,~,handles)
fieldnames(handles)
end

function button3(~,~,handles)
fieldnames(handles)
end
```

Push each button and look at the displayed output from `fieldnames`. You'll notice that button 1 only has `mainwindow`, button 2 has `mainwindow` and `button1`, and button3 has `mainwindow`, `button1`, and `button2`. As you've now noticed, no matter what changes you make elsewhere in your code, this result will remain constant.

It's an interesting quirk I noticed when I moved to programmatic GUIs rather than utilizing GUIDE. You generally don't notice with a GUIDE GUI because all of the initialization is taken care of in the background and the users don't tend to modify the handles structure. With a programmatic GUI you need to be conscious of the order in which you define your callbacks (define them after your handles structure is built).

The alternative is to utilize [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) like @YisasL said. Then you don't need to worry about passing variables to your callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand you.

Do you mean that I have to add guidata(hObject) to get the handles? So the code looks like this:

```
% --- Executes on button press in checkbox2.
function checkbox2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to checkbox2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of checkbox2
    handles
    guidata(hObject);
    handles
    handles.channelEnable(2) = get(hObject,'Value');
    guidata(hObject, handles);
end
```

It does not make any difference with or without. In both cases all handles are known (also channelEnable).